# How to adjust the spacing between figure and caption with Sidenotes and Subcaption package?

Tags: subcaption, sidenotes

Can anybody help me to adjust the spacing between `figure` and `caption` within the `sidenote` package? I would like to have the same spacing like without `\phantomsubcaption`

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt}
%



\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext

% With phantomsubcaption 
\begin{marginfigure}%
    {\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
                    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:MWEa}
                    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:MWEb}}
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%

% Without phantomsubcaption 
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.}%
    \label{fig:MWE}
\end{marginfigure}%
%

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:MWEb}%
                    \vspace{-\baselineskip}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you very much for quick answer!